# Reading Image from URL OpenCV Results in Larger File Size

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have an image processing app. The images are stored in an s3 bucket. I take the url and decode the image data. This works fine but the images are much bigger than the file size that shows in s3.

For example, one file will show 230kb in s3, but >500kb locally. I assume I'm doing something wrong when I read in the file data.

Also, I save the file as a `.jpg`. If I save it as a `.png`, then its even bigger.

```
def readFromUrl(url):
    resp = requests.get(url)
    return np.asarray(bytearray(resp.content), dtype="uint8")


def readFromUrlColor(url):
    nparr = readFromUrl(url)
    return cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

def readFromUrlGrayScale(url):
    nparr = readFromUrl(url)
    return cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

I am determing the file size by taking the result from `readFromUrlColor()` and then using `cv2.imwrite()` to save it.

I'm not very familiar with OpenCv. Am I doing something wrong?

### EDIT

I need to use OpenCV. PIL is not an option.

Thanks,

Comment: `imwrite` takes uncompressed data and compresses it. compression may use different parameters from how the file in that S3 bucket was created. write the encoded file 
data you receive, BEFORE decoding it. then it'll be the same size.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to save the images, this worked for me just fine and the file size was quite small.

```
import requests, io
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

def rgb_img(url):
    with open('img.jpg', 'wb') as file:
        file.write(requests.get(url).content)

def grayscale_img(url):
    img = requests.get(url).content
    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(img))
    img = ImageOps.grayscale(img)
    img.save('img.jpg')
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I should've have been more clear. I need to use OpenCv, not PIL.